# Java code superclass error

Tags: java

G'day!
I started programming literally yesterday and am now stuck at an @Override snippet I would like to include in a webview based app.

the problem is, that androids browser doesn't seem to recognize "tel:"-links. to solve that I added an override at the end. 
Any suggestions?

Thanks

```
package com.example.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.content.Intent;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {


private WebView mWebView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url)
{
    if (url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("sms:") || url.startsWith("smsto:") || url.startsWith("mms:") || url.startsWith("mmsto:"))
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: No idea what is the problem here... Please be more specific on what is an error / issue. What do you mean by 'androids browser'?

Comment: "Any suggestions?" <- telling us the actual problem you are facing would be good. Do you get a comiler error message? An exception when running the program? Or is it really just that the links don't get displayed the way you want it?

Comment: when I want to run the code I get the error
Error:(64, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
caused by the last @Override

Comment: Ok error is in line 64. Glad i could help:) Override error is because @override annotation should be use over methods that are inherited from parent class otherwise they serve no purpose. If you started programming yesterday you'd better start with some basics.

Comment: You added a new method that does not override an existing one. Adding the [@Override](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) annotation is therefor wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing with `@Override` is that you should only use that when you override a method from the superclass. In this case, you extend Activity. To use Override here, Activity needs to have that method. You should just remove the `@Override` and call said method in your onCreate.